# where field = CURDATE()

Tags: mysql

Такой запрос

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    integration_betapost.`tests_st`
WHERE
    add_date = CURDATE()
```

Который выводит всего две строки, где `add_date` равно `2017-06-02 00:00:00`,хотя в таблице есть много значений типа `2017-06-02 14:02:07`
Вопрос,почему они не попадают в выборку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно поле `add_date` привести к такому же формату `YYYY-MM-DD`, можно вот так:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    integration_betapost.`tests_st`
WHERE
    DATE(add_date) = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

Записи не попадают в выборку потому, что оператор `=` в MySQL требует строгого равенства аргументов, а `2017-06-02 00:00:00` не равно `2017-06-02 14:02:07`. Вы можете искать например все даты-время, которые больше начала текущего дня так:

```
SELECT * FROM integration_betapost.`tests_st`
 WHERE add_date >= CURDATE()
```

Или например взять записи от начала текущего дня до текущего времени в текущем дне:

```
SELECT * FROM integration_betapost.`tests_st`
 WHERE add_date between CURDATE() and NOW()
```

Или, например взять строго записи за текущие сутки:

```
SELECT * FROM integration_betapost.`tests_st`
 WHERE add_date >= CURDATE() and add_date < CURDATE()+INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Можно конечно явно привести колонку к дате, без времени (`date(add_date)=...`), но так делать не рекомендуется, так как в этом случае СУБД не сможет использовать индексы, даже если они есть. Что приведет к полному сканированию таблицы с соответствующей потерей производительности